# Is it possible to add a validation plugin to a config entity?

Tags: 8, entities

I have a configuration entity that I want to add custom validation to. I tried creating a Validation Plugin (as described here: https://www.drupalwatchdog.com/volume-5/issue-2/introducing-drupal-8s-entity-validation-api), which I've previously created successfully for a content entity.

It doesn't seem to be working for my config entity though. I'm not sure if it's because I've made a mistake somewhere, or if it's just not possible add a validation plugin to a config entity.

Can someone confirm one way or the other?

Comment: I think @larowlan's answer is still valid. Yes, it is possible, but it is not out-of-the-box, and you would need to add your own code to do so. That's probably why most config validate in FAPI only.